# Maintaining Method Signatures across languages?

Tags: porting, coding-standards

I'm finishing up a port I did of a portion of a Java Library. The library calculates sunrise and sunset for a given latitude and longitude. The original Java library also calculated various times based on sunrise and sunset, which I plan to get to later.

That said,  I'm working with Objective-C and the Cocoa touch framework. The original methods, being Java, all began with `get` and took their arguments in parenthesis. However, Objective-C has a different method structure, so the methods end up looking different. For example,

`public double getUTCSunset(AstronomicalCalendar astronomicalCalendar,
            double zenith, boolean adjustForElevation)`

becomes this:

`- (double) getUTCSunsetForDate:(NSDate*)date andZenith:(double)zenith adjustForElevation:(BOOL)adjustForElevation`.

The problem here is twofold. First of all, according to the Apple Documentation on coding convention, method names (and "getters"), should not include `get` in them. However, a second issue arises if we drop the `get`. We end up with a method signature that begins with a capital letter, which is also not supposed to happen.

How would you rewrite this method, while keeping the method signatures similar enough to be recognizable to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`- (double) UTCSunsetForDate:(NSDate*)date andZenith:(double)zenith adjustForElevation:(BOOL)adjustForElevation`

I think you can start with a capital letter if it's an acronym. Look at [NSURLRequest class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) where some methods begin with `URL` or `HTTP`.

Actually, here's a quote from [Apple coding guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF)

> Start the name with a lowercase letter
>   and capitalize the first letter of
>   embedded words. Don’t use prefixes.
>   See “Typographic Conventions.” There
>   are two specific exceptions to these
>   guidelines. You may begin a method
>   name with a well-known acronym in
>   uppercase (such as TIFF or PDF)), and
>   you may use prefixes to group and
>   identify private methods (see “Private
>   Methods”).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really been writing a lot of Objective C these days, but I would expect a method signature like this:

```
- (double) utcSunsetForDate:(NSDate*)date andZenith:(double)zenith adjustingForElevation:(BOOL)adjustForElevation
```

'utc' doesn't look as great, but it's definitely better than 'uTC', 'getUTC' or even 'universalCoordinatedTime', which is just way too verbose.

Also, should the return valu really be a double, rather than a UTCTime or something similar?